# CSS Media Query for multiple resolutions

Tags: ipad, html, css, tablet, media-queries

I am looking at using CSS Media Query to support multiple tablets (Android/iPad). Below is the Media Query which I have;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width:1024px)" href="css/tablet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width:1024px)" href="css/desktop.css">
```

Now my assumption is most tablets are below 1024px width. Please correct me on this front. Any tabular comparision would be great.

Also any other approaches besides device-width for media query would be fine.

I am looking at a generic way of designing my pages which would work for both desktop/tablet browsers...present and future (and may be even mobile). I am using fluid design (or called responsive design) for the same (everything in %...width/height/padding/margin all in %)

Comment: Are you trying to base it on resolution or on the device being a tablet versus desktop?  If you just want to target tablets, I wouldn't use resolution.  This will definitely break within 6 months as resolutions get larger.  There are already tablets with resolutions higher than 1024px.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_tablet_computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that a device such as an iPad can be used in both portrait and landscape orientations, so I would use the following media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

    /* .touch class from Modernizr */
    .touch .element {color: #fff;}

}
```

Or if you'd like to keep the styles in their own document:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width:1024px)" href="css/tablet.css">`

**Note:** You could generally detect tablets by combining media queries with a feature detection library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: I am aware of how to target only the iPad...I am looking at a generic way of writing the media query for multiple tablets..

Comment: It's tough; a galaxy tab is 1280x800 which you might find on 'netbooks' as well.  Unfortunately, your best bet is likely user agent sniffing if you are trying to set up different behaviors based on the device class.

Comment: I updated the answer to mention detecting touch-event support.